# How can I get HTTP request headers in Node.js application after executing POST request

Tags: node.js, cookies, xmlhttprequest

In java, cookies (present as a part of request headers) can be accessed using cookie store:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// execute get/post/put or whatever
httpClient.doGetPostPutOrWhatever();
// get cookieStore
CookieStore cookieStore = httpClient.getCookieStore();
// get Cookies 
List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
```

How to access cookie store or request headers in node.js application?
I am using XMLHttpRequest in the node.js based application. However, it does not support anything like getCookieStore(). xhr.getResponseHeader('Cookie') does not work as cookies are not present as part of response.